# Using pd.cut to create bins for a graph, but bin values are not coming out as expected

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is the code I'm running:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic") 
y =titanic.groupby([titanic.fare//1,'sex']).survived.mean().reset_index()  #grouping by 'fare' rounded to an integer and 'sex' and then getting the survivability 

x =pd.cut(y.fare, (0,17,35,70,300,515)) #I'm not sure if my format is correct but this is how I cut up the fare values  


y['Fare_bins']= x   # adding the newly created bins to a new column "Fare_bins' in original dataframe.  



#graphing with seaborn


sns.set(style="whitegrid")
g = sns.factorplot(x='Fare_bins', y= 'survived', col = 'sex', kind ='bar' ,data= y,
           size=4, aspect =2.5 , palette="muted")
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("Survival Probability")
g.set_xlabels('Fare')
plt.show()
```

The problem I'm having is that Fare_values are showing up as (0,17].
The left side is a  circle bracket and the right side is square bracket.
If possible I would like to have something like this:
    (0-17) or [0-17]

Next, there seems to be a gap between each bar plot. I was expecting them to be adjoined. There are two graphs being represented, so I don't expect of the bars to be ajoined, but the first 5 bars(first graph)should be connected and the last 5 bars to eachother(second graph).

How can I go about fixing these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can add labels. 
Just by adding labels to the "cut" method parameters, I can display the Fare_values as I want.

```
x =pd.cut(y.fare, (0,17,35,70,300,515), labels = ('(0-17)', '(17-35)', '(35-70)', '(70-300)','(300-515)') )
```

As for the brackets showing around the fare_value groups, 
according to the documentation:

```
right : bool, optional

Indicates whether the bins include the rightmost edge or not. If right == True (the default), then the bins [1,2,3,4] indicate (1,2], (2,3], (3,4].
```

Still not sure if it's possible to join the bars though.